# 2 LinearLayouts in the same position

Tags: android, android-layout

So what I am trying to do is to have 2 invisible `LinearLayout`s with buttons they will be from the start to the screen.

On the `onClick` event one of them will appear with a translate animation,when the other is invisible and then on the other `onClick` event to close the open one and open the new one.
It will look similar to a sliding menu with the animation.

I want to know how the xml will look like in order to do that.
If it's possible with other layout (`RelativeLayout`), I also want to know.

Any tips on that?

Comment: I haven't tried something yet in xml. That's why I want some start on how maybe I will do it or some sites for tips. (I already have seen in the android.developers site about LinearLayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it.

1. Relative Layout definitely being the one as you your self know. :)
2. Add both the LinearLayouts with layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="match_parent" and then toggle between them using setVisibility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). Since View.GONE will remove one Linear Layout the other one will occupy the entire screen in its absence and vice versa.
3. You can also use FrameLayout. This by default places its children on top of each other.

Suit yourself. :)

Comment: So RelativeLayout is parent and 2 linearlayout inside, is that what you are trying to say? in 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, if you wanna use Relative Layout then do step 1 and 2 together, else only option 2 will also be enough.